# Using CSS Imports in Styled Components with React CSS Syntax

Tags: css, reactjs, jss, google-fonts

Problem is basically I need to know how to use `@import` in React CSS to use with Styled Components. I tried something but does not work, font can not be imported like below.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div({
    '@import': 'url(`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap`)',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    fontSize: '0.8em',
    margin: '20px',
    width: '400px'
})
```

I expect that works but not, I think there's a syntax problem that I don't know.

And, I have to tell I don't use below syntax.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 400px;
`
```

This code works, I know. But this is not what I need so please do not recommend solutions which contains template literals and local font imports.

Answer (score -1):

I always import fonts like this in a seperate CSS file:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
    
.wrapper {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

If you want to use it in a styled component, give this a read:

https://dev.to/alaskaa/how-to-import-a-web-font-into-your-react-app-with-styled-components-4-1dni

Comment: Thank you, but as I specified I don't use local imports and it's explaining local imports with styled components.